# django can't use context processor in some templates

Tags: python, django

Why i can't use my custom context_processor in some templates?
On mail templates, it doesn't work, or on template that extends homepage..

context_processor.py:

```
from django.conf import settings

def settings_processor(request):
    my_dict = {
        'SITE_URL': '%s%s' % ('https://' if request.is_secure() else 'http://', request.META['HTTP_HOST']),
        'SITE_NAME': settings.SITE_NAME,
        'LANG': 'asdasdsa'
    }

    return my_dict
```

settings.py:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = TCP + (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'project.context_processors.settings_processor',
)
```

Comment: No log, no error, nothing?

Comment: Nothing, just like i didn't call it..

Comment: And are you using RequestContext to render those templates?

Comment: I use generic view, ListView..